# Finding the Min and Max numbers using Dialog boxes Java

Tags: java

So my assignment is this

Ask the user to input a number.  You should use an input dialog box for this input.  Be sure to convert the String from the dialog box into a real number.  The program needs to keep track of the smallest number the user entered as well as the largest number entered.  Ask the user if they want to enter another number.  If yes, repeat the process.  If no, output the smallest and largest number that the user entered.

This program outputs the largest and smallest number AT THE END of the program when the user wants to quit.

Also, your program should account for the case when the user only enters one number.  In that case, the smallest and largest number will be the same.

I am having a hard time making it if the user only enters 1 number then both values will be set but at the same time making it loop as long as the user says yes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{      
    int maxNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String repeat;
    String firstResponseString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number ");
    maxNum = Integer.parseInt(firstResponseString);
    minNum = Integer.parseInt(firstResponseString);
    String userRepeat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Would you like to input another number? Y/N");
    while(userRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        String num1String = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Numer: ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1String);
        if(num1 > maxNum)
           {
               maxNum = num1;
           }
        if(num1 < minNum)
           {
               minNum = num1;
           }  
        userRepeat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Would you like to input another number? Y/N"); 
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Largest Number: " + maxNum + "\nSmallest Number: " + minNum, "Find Min and Max", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}
```

I think I got it working now with this code

Comment: Why don't you share what you've done so far and we can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.  You have to show us what you've done so far for anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: What is the exact problem? When the user enters the first number, immediately assign that value to minimum and maximum. Then when the user quits, just display them.

Comment: I think i got it I am pretty sure this is working pretty well at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You may set the `int minNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `int maxNum = Ingerer.MAX_VALUE` in declaration.

Comment: Thanks that helped to get me going to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

The String repeat serves no purpose since it's not used anywhere but in the declaration also the assignment of maxNum=... and minNum=.... is unnecessary since you're parsing the maxNum and minNum so they can be recognized by the JOptionpane.